# Allowing permission to Generate a policy based on CloudTrail events where the selected Trail logs events in an S3 bucket in another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-iam-access-analyzer

I have an AWS account (Account A) with CloudTrail enabled and logging management events to an S3 'logs' bucket in another, dedicated logs account (Account B, which I also own).

The logging part works fine, but I'm now trying (and failing) to use the 'Generate policy based on CloudTrail events' tool in the IAM console (under the Users > Permissions tab) in Account A.

This is supposed to read the CloudTrail logs for a given user/region/no. of days, identify all of the actions the user performed, then generate a sample IAM security policy to allow only those actions, which is great for setting up least privilege policies etc.

When I first ran the generator, it created a new service role to assume in the same account (Account A): AccessAnalyzerMonitorServiceRole_ABCDEFGHI

When I selected the CloudTrail trail to analyse, it (correctly) identified that the trail logs are stored in an S3 bucket in another account, and displayed this warning messsage:

> Important: Verify cross-account access is configured for the selected
> trail The selected trail logs events in an S3 bucket in another
> account. The role you choose or create must have read access to the
> bucket in that account to generate a policy. Learn more.

Attempting to run the generator at this stage fails after a short amount of time, and if you hover over the 'Failed' status in the console you see the message:

> Incorrect permissions assigned to access CloudTrail S3 bucket. Please
> fix before trying again.

Makes sense, but actually giving read access to the S3 bucket to the automatically generated AccessAnalyzerMonitorServiceRole_ABCDEFGHI is where I'm now stuck!

I'm relatively new to AWS so I might have done something dumb or be missing something obvious, but I'm trying to give the automatically generated role in Account A permission to the S3 bucket by adding to the 'Bucket Policy' attached to the S3 logs bucket in our Account B. I've added the below extract to the existing bucket policy (which is just the standard policy for a CloudTrail logs bucket, extended to allow CloudTrail in Account A to write logs to it as well.

```
    "Sid": "IAMPolicyGeneratorRead",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/service-role/AccessAnalyzerMonitorServiceRole_ABCDEFGHI"
    },
    "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetObjectVersion",
        "s3:ListBucket"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::aws-cloudtrail-logs-ABCDEFGHI",
        "arn:aws:s3:::aws-cloudtrail-logs-ABCDEFGHI/*"
    ]
}
```

Any suggestions how I can get this working?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I just needed to follow the steps described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access-analyzer-policy-generation.html#access-analyzer-policy-generation-cross-account in the section 'Generate a policy using AWS CloudTrail data in another account', specifically for the 'Object Ownership' settings in addition to changing my Bucket Policy to match the example.